# Image in UICollectionView not displaying changes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with many items. I am using this for a shop and I want to edit the content in the cell when it is clicked. When I click on the cell, just for test, I remove the background, but it never gets removed when I click the cell. when I add a print function it still prints out so I know this method is being called.

I have a UICollectionView class with the function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Shop1CollectionViewCell

    cell.clickedOn()
   collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

I have a class for the cells:

```
class Shop1CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Label: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var background: UIImageView!

func clickedOn(){
    background.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
   }

}
```

Is there anything I can do so it will update the content in the cell. It seems like it is locked in some way to not be changed, or is constantly resetting the images.

Comment: I have more code in the CollectionView class if needed but for now, it doesn't seem necessary to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Shop1CollectionViewCell
```

with

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! Shop1CollectionViewCell
```

As `dequeueReusableCell` returns another cell not the one you click , also you may save this change to that cell as not to be dequeued by other index

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. Will accept once the time limit runs out